# How to properly align form elements with SwiftUI on macOS? LazyVGrid?

Tags: macos, swiftui

As an exercise, I am trying to replicate the "Advanced" preference pane from Safari on macOS (Big Sur), like so (without the nav bar):

screenshot of safari Advanced preferences

[image]

I am wondering what the right way is to properly align all the elements in the window, both horizontally and vertically. I have done a first attempt using a `LazyVGrid` and it is pretty close but I have a few questions:

1. Is `LazyVGrid` the way to do it, or is there a better way?
2. With enough elements, I quickly run out of the 10-limit for the view constructor. I had to resort to a super-kludgy builder function combined with a `ForEach` and `AnyView`s everywhere. What is a better way?
3. Things line up pretty well except for the Accessibility section, where "Accessibility" is not lined up perfectly with the first toggle "Never use fonts larger than...". In the Safari case, they line up perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
struct PrefsAdvancedView: View {
    let emptyCell = AnyView(Color(NSColor.clear))

    @Binding var bool1: Bool
    @Binding var bool2: Bool

    @State private var selectedStrength = "9"
    let strengths = [ "9" ]
    @State private var selectedSheet = "None Selected"
    let sheets = [ "None Selected", "fake1" ]
    @State private var selectedEncoding = "Western (ISO Latin 1)"
    let encodings = [ "Western (ISO Latin 1)", "fake1" ]


    private let columns = [GridItem(.fixed(150), alignment: .trailing),
                           GridItem(.fixed(300), alignment: .leading)]

    func buildGrid(_ index: Int) -> AnyView {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return AnyView(Text("Smart Search Field:"))
        case 1:
            return AnyView(Toggle("Show full website address", isOn: $bool1))
        case 2:
            return AnyView(
                VStack {
                    Text("Accessibility:")
                    Spacer()
                })
        case 3:
            return AnyView(
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Toggle("Never use font sizes smaller than", isOn: $bool2)
                        Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: EmptyView()) {
                            ForEach(strengths, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: 50)
                        .disabled(!bool2)
                    }
                    Toggle("Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage", isOn: $bool2)
                    Text("Option-Tab highlights each item")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                })
        case 4:
            return AnyView(Text("Reading List:"))
        case 5:
            return AnyView(Toggle("Save articles for offline reading automatically", isOn: $bool2))
        case 6:
            return AnyView(Text("Style sheet:"))
        case 7:
            return AnyView(Picker(selection: $selectedSheet, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach(sheets, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            )
        case 8:
            return AnyView(Text("Default encoding:"))
        case 9:
            return AnyView(Picker(selection: $selectedEncoding, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach(encodings, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            )
        case 10:
            return AnyView(Text("Proxies:"))
        case 11:
            return AnyView(Button("Change Settings...", action: { }))
        //14: Empty
        case 13:
            return AnyView(Toggle("Show Develop menu in menu bar", isOn: $bool1))

        default:
            return emptyCell
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<14) { index in // Kudlgy. What's the right way?
                    buildGrid(index)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

And here's what it looks like when running:

screenshot of SwiftUI-based preference pane

[image]

Comment: If there are not specific issues and just want to know the "right-way" this question seems more inline with [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Stackoverflow is more [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions about problems and algorithms.

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum. The first of three questions is a "right-way" question indeed, but question 2 and 3 are more "how do you make this work properly?" so hopefully I can get some answers here. I'll check out Code Review.

Comment: @vmallet were you able to get any more advice on this? Or is LazyVGrid the way to go?

Comment: `Grid` still in beta is great for this, refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid